# How to use ruby-linter in visual studio code?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, linter

I am a really newcomer for both **ruby** and **visual studio code**. I have installed `ruby` and `ruby-debug-ide`, and I can run or debug the ruby in vscode already. Now I would like to install the [ruby-linter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.ruby-linter), but it doesn't work. For example, when I write `Random.r` it shows nothing which is expected to be `rand`, anyone can help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to install the [ruby extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby#user-content-linters) on Visual Studio Code and follow the instructions on the documentation to set it up, it works properly both on Windows and Linux, provided that you have Ruby installed.

The extension can be configured for debugging with [ruby_debug_ide](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug-ide) and [debase](https://rubygems.org/gems/debase) that can be installed with ...

```
$ sudo gem install ruby-debug-ide
$ sudo gem install debase
```

...linting can be provided by ruby itself, adding on Visual Studio Code settings file that can be accessed by typing **"CTRL+P" > Settings**...

```
"ruby.lint": {
    "ruby": true,
}
```

...and intellisense can be provided by [rcodetools](https://rubygems.org/gems/rcodetools) or [solargraph](https://rubygems.org/gems/solargraph) that can be installed with...

```
$ sudo gem install rcodetools
$ sudo gem install solargraph
```